# Production Views not returning results intermittently in Java SDK 2.5. 0

Tags: java, mapreduce, couchbase

Couchbase Server: 5.1.0

Couchbase Java SDK: 2.5.0

I am using below code in my application. And is returning no data intermittently, where there is data in the server. I am using Production view only. Please help me to resolve this issue.

```
List keys = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(“TEST_CATEGORY”));
ViewQuery query = ViewQuery.from(“dataSelector”,“dataSelector”);
query.stale(Stale.FALSE);
JsonArray keyJsonArrays = JsonArray.from(keys);
query.keys(keyJsonArrays);
List resultList = new ArrayList();
bucket.query(query).forEach(p-> resultList.add(p.id()));

//ViewQuery(dataSelector/dataSelector){params=“stale=false”, keys="[“TEST_CATEGORY”]"}
logger.debug("queryViewByKeys() query: "+query.toString());
```

Comment: I'm not much a Java dev, but I believe bucket.query returns some kind of Result object. Have you examined that object to see if any errors or exceptions are returned? Also, is there any information in the logs that might indicate what is going on?